# Pseudocode: does this make sense?

Tags: pseudocode

Does the below make sense in pseudocode?
It's a fairly simple beginner program.

1. Start program
2. Print welcome message text main menu
3. Print ticket type options text main menu
4. Prompt user for ticket option
5. Prompt user for number of tickets
6. Prompt user for confirmation
7. If confirmation is not 1 prompt user to return to main menu
8. If confirmation equals 1 proceed next step
9. Compute total = ticket option type cost * number of tickets
10. Print confirmation total price
11. End Program

Comment: Yes it makes sense

Comment: I think, You should use alignment(give 8 spaces to second if) to separate whether if statements are nested or not.

Comment: You should know that pseudo code is not programming language specific

Comment: ... which is why it is 'pseudo'. It also has nothing to do with blue suede shoes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but try to write it a bit differently, with formatting and actual pseudo code instructions (not English language). It will show the logic better. For example

```
// start program
showMainMenu() // welcome message and ticket type options
var option = prompt("Enter a ticket option")
var numTickets = prompt("Enter the number of tickets")
var confirmation = prompt("Press 1 to confirm")
if (confirmation != 1) {
    var backToMain = prompt("Press 1 to return to main menu")
    // TODO implement this, your code misses it
} else {
    // confirmation is 1 here, proceed to next step
    var total = ticketCost(option) * numTickets
    printf("Confirmation total price: %d", total)
}
// end program
```